# How do i access childNode of <label> using document.getElementsByClassName()?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<span class="mtb-price">
<label Class="mtb-ofr"><b class="lb1"></b>AAAAA</label></span>
<script>
var sku = document.getElementsByClassName("mtb-ofr").childNodes[1].nodeValue;
alert(sku);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do i access childNode of  having class name 'mtb-ofr' using document.getElementsByClassName() ?
and what should be the alternative of document.getElementsByClassName() to obtain the same result ??

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("mtb-ofr")[0].childNodes` ? or just `.children`.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array, you need to select an item of the array before you can drill down any deeper

Comment: Basically what i want is to replace AAAAA with some other text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to change the label's text:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mtb-ofr")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue = 'something';
```

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array.  You need to first get the element from the NodeList.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mtb-ofr")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue
```

Comment: @Rocket hey thanks it works. will this work in IE8 i mean document.getElementsByClassName()

Comment: @PoojaDesai: Pretty sure that `getElementsByClassName` doesn't work in IE 8.

Comment: than what should be solution for that ?

Comment: @PoojaDesai: You can try `document.querySelectorAll('.mtb-ofr')` instead. (Or a JS library like jQuery).

Comment: @rambocoder: I guess the OP wanted to set the value, not just get it.  w/e.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery !

```
$('label.mtb-ofr').children()
```

You're done !

And you can filter more by passing parameters to children().

http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: hey thats nice but i want using javascript.

Comment: While I love jQuery, I don't think you should jump to it for everything unless you're actually going to use it to its full potential. And we don't know that here... so a simple JS solution would be better.

Comment: agree with the other commenters, but this doesn't deserve downvotes imo